# If i was send a payment by a money making app but my paypal account os not yet to be receiving payment because of the financial laws of my country

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

Kk if the payment reaches 30 days and I haven't claim the payments will I have to reclaim the payment or I can't have access to the payments anymore ,note that PayPal hasn't add a receiving payment to my account

Answer (score 0):

After 30 days, unclaimed PayPal payments are returned to the sender and can no longer be claimed.

Claiming them requires confirming the email address on a PayPal account from a country that is able to receive payments.